# How do I add the user inputs together?

Tags: python, function

```
number = 0

def sumDigits(number):
    while True:
        number = int(input("Please enter a number (enter 0 to exit):"))
        if number == 0:
            sum = number + number
            print("The sum is",sum)
            break

print(sumDigits(number))
```

After 0 is entered, the program outputs "The sum is 0" and then on the next line it outputs "None" I'm not sure what's happening out why the "None" is there.

I need the program to add all the user inputs together.

Comment: Look at the line `sum = number + number`.  Which `number` is which here?  You're just adding the number to itself, but only if the user types `0`.  You need to keep the total in its own variable and then add the input to that.

Comment: by typing `print(sumDigits(number))` you print out the `return value` of `sumDigits`. As you do not return anything, it automatically returns `None`, which gets printed. Look into return values

Comment: How would I do that? I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: don't name a variable sum, it's a built-in python function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a list, and append all the values the user enters to that list. Then use the built-in `sum` function (to add all the values in the list), and return the result.

```
number = 0
lst = []
def sumDigits():
    while True:
        number = int(input("Please enter a number (enter 0 to exit):"))
        lst.append(number)
        if number == 0:
            add = sum(lst)
            return f"The sum is {add}"
            break
            

print(sumDigits())
```

Your program wouldn't work previously because you are just adding the current numbers the player entered which was always `0`, and you weren't returning any values, which is why you got a `None`.

Another side-note: Do not name the variable `sum`, because it is a built-in function as I said above.

Also, there is no need for the number argument in your function as well because it is not being used.

Comment: Can you explain what is the `number` in the function `signature`?   Because the program is taking user `input` directly.  Did not see the `need` for it there!

Comment: I suspect the OP is thinking to use `number` (function signature) as the signal to end the program. But it's not clear to me... and no one seems try to follow up or explain it.

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice that when editing the code. I don't know why it's there, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable to hold the total, and add to it each time through the loop.

```
def sumDigits(number):
    total = 0
    while True:
        number = int(input("Please enter a number (enter 0 to exit):"))
        if number == 0:
            print("The sum is",total)
            break
        total += number
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes.
First of them is if you do `print(sumDigits(number))`, then you print the return value of the sumDigits function. You do this by using the "return" keyword.
Second is the line `sum = number + number`. Problem number one here is that sum is a built-in function and that means you must not use it as a variable identifier. Problem number two is that in this case sum equals the same number times two, not two different numbers added.

What you want to do is something like following:

```
number = 0

def sumDigits(number):
    while True:
        new_number = int(input("Please enter a number (enter 0 to exit): "))
        if not new_number == 0:
            number += new_number
        else: break

print(sumDigits(number))
```